# Listen to incomming SMS with iOS Jailbreak app

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak

Does anyone know how to listen to incomming sms on jailbroken iOS? I want to search in its content for an given String and show an alerts if it matches.

Thx,
Patrick

Comment: You should class-dump Messages.app, hook it, and post darwin notifications to your app if you find a match (not sure NSNotificationCenter would work between domains)

Comment: maybe this other question helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122998/how-to-block-incoming-sms-in-iphone-jailbreak-code

Comment: @tkanzakic 's link show that the notification I talk about already exist internally, so you could just listen for kCTSMSMessageReceivedNotification :)

Comment: See [this Q+A, too](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10681995/119114)